# Haproxy 1.8 and cache

Tags: caching, haproxy

In version 1.8 of Haproxy, it is possible to use a cache. We do not need a big cache and so that might be enough.
This while I have one or two questions, is it possible to know what exactly hides this cache, and how?

The following command

watch -n 1 "echo" show cache "| nc -U /var/lib/haproxy/haproxy.sock"

do not return much understandable. If not, can nuster be a good alternative?

We host Tomcat servers / intranet applications.

Thank you in advance for your possible answers.

Patrick.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: It's for 2 webapp's and 2 webservices Java EE,  consulted by 2000 persons per day, maybe less. embedded on Tomcat 7 in GNU/Linux system. I have configured an HA infrastructure with haproxy & keepalived, and we would like to know if the only cache of haproxy is enough, and especially how to know what it put on the cache ? Thank's a lot for your help.

Comment: The cache in haproxy1.8 has many limitations, for example only small response can be cached, which defaults to 16KB as defined by the global parameter tune.bufsize, while nuster can cache any size response. Also haproxy1.8 cache only works for 200 and GET, while nuster can cache any http code and POST/PUT. Also haproxy1.8 cache can only use host and uri as key, while nuster can use header, cookie, query as key too. And nuster has PURGE functionalities, disable/enable at runtime , stats, and so on

Comment: thank you very much for your explanations.

Comment: Hi,I would like to know how nuster works with haproxy? You do not mention it in your doc on github. We have a haproxy for loadbalancing and we would also like to have a cache without having to install an apache.

Comment: We have JavaEE middleware applications tomcat / wildfly. Does Haproxy and Nuster work together? Do you have a doc? Haproxy listens on the: 80 and nuster on the: 8080 we have keepalived in frontend to make high availability haproxy level. thank you in advance for the answer.

client---vip|keepalived--haproxy--(nuster) or varnish --wilfly2.1.8--------oracle12
                  keepalived---haproxy-(nuster)-----------------wildfly2.18-------oracle

Comment: I would like to test nuster instead of varnish. Thanks

Comment: Hi, https://dev.to/nuster/comment/4gni

Comment: I did, however, look for I had not seen this post.
Thank you ;)

Comment: I think there is an error at the end of your tutorial, you say kill haproxy and run nuster look like:

#/usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf

I think it is

#/usr/local/nuster/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf

Comment: You are right, corrected it